# LSP :: No LSP server for go-mode (check *lsp-log*)

Tags: golang, doom

I'm try to setup my golang IDE on doom-emacs.

I've go installed

```
    $ go version
    go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64
```

gopath is set -

```
    $ echo $GOPATH
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/go
```

$PATH is set as -

```
    $ echo $PATH
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.cargo/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.local/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/current/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/n/bin:/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/go/bin
```

As you see `$GOPATH/bin` is in `$PATH`.

`gopls` is installed as well -

```
    $ which gopls
    /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/go/bin/gopls

    $ gopls version
    golang.org/x/tools/gopls 0.4.1
        golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.4.1 h1:0e3BPxGV4B3cd0zdMuccwW72SgmHp92lAjOyxX/ScAw=
```

But when I open a gocode in file I get error `LSP :: No LSP server for go-mode (check *lsp-log*)`

[image: golsp error]

I check this [comment][2go mod init /root/TestApp] in github If I do `SPC h d d` I didn't get anything

Below is the M-x getenv RET PATH RET result -

[image: PATH doom emacs]

Note - My Os is macos sierra 10.12.6 version

I tested this in fedora as well and same issue is happening.

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
    Distributor ID: Fedora
    Description:    Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
    Release:        31
    Codename:       ThirtyOne
```

Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is `$GOPATH/bin` in your path from within emacs? `M-x getenv RET PATH RET`?

Comment: @psanford - `$GOPATH/bin` is not in the path within emacs. Thanks for your hint. How can I add there as well?

Comment: Are you sure your Os is macOS? That screenshot appears to be fedora.

Comment: What did you see when you checked `*lsp-log*`? (Ie changed to that buffer and had a look)

Comment: If you start emacs from the terminal it will inherit the PATH you set in the terminal. Or you can set the path directly in emacs via `(setenv "PATH" "/path/a:path/b/:path/c")`

Comment: @DanRobertson -  I tested in macOs and fedora both

Comment: @psanford - I tried `M-x setenv`. But once I restart the emacs the settings are gone.

Comment: You can add it to your emacs config file to make it permanent.